# C# dynamically access variables based on user input

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic

I am new to C# but have school project that i am working on and need some guidance. 
I have multiple arrays which i termed array1, array2, array3 , array4 and so on till array9. 
Now the user is entering digits into input box and i am splitting the input like 543 into 5 4 3
and i want to dynamically call

array5 array4 array3. So basically show contents of these arrays in console.

string value = input.Text.ToString();

```
 foreach (string s in Array[value[0]])
    {
    -- will loop through all values of array and out put
    foreach (string s in Array[value[1]])
      {
       -- will loop through all values of array and out put
          foreach (string s in Array[value[2]])
          {
          -- will loop through all values of array and out put
          }
       }
    }
```

How do i accomplish this ? Please help

Comment: Why are there 9 array variables? The entire point of collections is to eliminate multiplicity from variables.

Comment: I don't understand either. Are you trying to make an array for each number?

Comment: Do array or arrays: array[9][n], now you can access to X array, for example array[4][2] = ...

Comment: @user2864740  Yes those are just array names i used for example. So array will have different items in them like collections which will get selected once user enters the desired numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var arrays = new List<int[]>(){array1,....,array9};
```

and then if you have 5, 4, 3 you can call arrays like

```
arrays[4], arrays[3], arrays[2]
```

Comment: I did that but it says var the type or namespace cannot be found c#

Comment: then read more about what is var ... you have another mistake, I assume you have problem with brackets

Comment: This is what i typed
var arrays = new List<int[]>{Array2,Array3,Array4,Array5,Array6,Array7,Array8,Array9};

Comment: important is, where you typed this code. Are you inside of method or constructor? Probably not. Code more, ask less ;)

Comment: Here's my code. Its just frustrating :(   
'string[] Array2 = new string[3] { "A", "B", "C" };
            string[] Array3 = new string[3] { "D", "E", "F" };
            string[] Array5 = new string[3] { "J", "K", "L" };
            string[] Array6 = new string[3] { "M", "N", "O" };
            string[] Array7 = new string[3] { "P", "R", "S" };
            string[] Array8 = new string[3] { "T", "U", "V" };
            string[] Array9 = new string[3] { "W", "X", "Y" };
            List<int[]> data = new List<int[]> { Array2, Array3, Array4, Array5, Array6, Array7, Array8, Array9 };'

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of the file?